# Blank desktop background after purging wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel

After purging wingpanel and then installing it again, I rebooted and logged in. The login interface disappeared as usual but nothing else happened there was just the background image. I had this problem before and I fixed it by reinstalling pantheon (at least I think that's what I did, can't remember) however it doesn't seem to be working now (ctrl+alt+f2)

Comment: Why did you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by removing and install pantheon.

```
sudo apt-get remove pantheon
sudo apt-get install pantheon
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Please mark this question as "Solving the question".

Answer (score 0):

Try to return Cerbere to default:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.cerbere monitored-processes ['wingpanel', 'plank', 'slingshot-launcher --silent']
```